# How can I get the full value of a variable while debugging Apex?

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test, debugging

I'm using VS Code with the salesforce extensions to debug a test method. A query executed by the method is returning no records when I think it should be returning one. So I click on the "Debug Test" link above the test definition, but when I get to where the query string is being defined and try to see its value, all I get is this:

```
'SELECT Id, Name, (SE (2787 more) ...'
```

How can I see what the full query string is at that point?

Comment: Is it a static query or a dynamic one? If the former, you should be able to just find it in the code.

Comment: It's a dynamic query.

Answer (score 0):

To get the full output, you need to actually use System.debug, as in:

```
System.debug(queryString);
```